# Call function when user leaves the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Hi, I  have button, that close the edit mode. That button use the 'editMode' function.
> I want to call it, when user navigate to any other page or update the page.

```
            <Box data-automation-id="button-fast-adding-close" onClick={editMode} sx={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                <CloseIcon />
            </Box>
```

How can I use 'editMode' for the actions, that I described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger the function when your component [unmounts](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unmounting). With react hooks you can do it like this

```
useEffect(() => () => editMode(), []);
```

Comment: Do you think it will be called when a page is refreshed?

Comment: @zerkms No, but the question says that it closes the edit mode. If the edit mode is closed on page load, refresh will work as expected because the component will reset state anyway

Comment: yeah, it works with f5 actually